# Finding a power series solution for an ODE at a point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

You have to find a power series solution about $x = 0$ to the ordinary differential equation for $y = y(x)$:

$$y′′ −xy′ +(x+1)y = x$$

I have only ever done this with homogenous ODE's and not autonomous ones. Not sure were to start or what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The idea is the same, plug-in your series and see what happens.

Comment: Are you saying that autonomous is the opposite of homogeneous ?

Comment: Hint: $$\sum n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-n\sum a_nx^n+\sum a_nx^{n+1}+\sum a_nx^n=x.$$

Comment: SHOULD IT not be -x instead of -n for the term representingg y'

Comment: and shouldn't (x+1) be in front of the last sigma term

Comment: and should the limits be n=2 to infinity; n=1 to infinity and n=0 to infinity respectively